# Topic Modelling - I have used NMF and LDA, what is next?

Tags: python, nlp, lda, topic-modeling, nmf

I have used NMF and LDA for topic modelling in Python, with what I would call good results with NMF, and poor results with LDA.

My data is highly domain specific, with a lot of unique/specific vocabulary.

I am trying to improve my NMF output by trying some other methods.

Can anyone recommend what I should research/learn yet?

thanks

Comment: It may be better to post this question to [CrossValidated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/) or [AI}(https://ai.stackexchange.com/) StackExchange forum.

Answer (score 1):

May be PCA?
Table 2 and Table 4
https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC7861298/

Comment: thanks. how can I use PCA when my dataset is text/string format? Sorry for dumb question